# Socket.io connection with a ec2 instance AWS

Tags: javascript, socket.io

i'm new to the world of sockets, i'll try to explain my problem. I have an AWS server with an ec2 instance and I would like to allow the chat of my application which relies on socket.io to send messages through this server and not the localhost. locally the application works but I can't connect it to the ec2 server as it gives me a connection error, I checked my inbound rules and opened port 3000 and inbound traffic. I'm really freaking out, any help would be welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i don't need an advice with the code  because i totally confused and i don't know 
where to start